# How can I receive message by golang - whisper

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, whisper

In `geth --shh --rpc console`, for example I type

```
f = shh.newMessageFilter({privateKeyId: id}, function(error, messages){console.log(JSON.stringify(messages))})
```

to receive a posted message by callback, and this works fine.

I am trying by golang to receive a posted message but this not work

example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    shh "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/whisper/shhclient"
    whisper "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/whisper/whisperv6"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.TODO()

    c, err := shh.Dial("http://127.0.0.1:8545")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    id, _ := c.NewKeyPair(ctx)
    fmt.Println("id:", id)

    fID, err := c.NewMessageFilter(ctx, whisper.Criteria{PrivateKeyID: id})
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("FilterId:", fID)

    puKey, err := c.PublicKey(ctx, id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("PublicKey:", hexutil.Encode(puKey))

    blk, err := c.Post(ctx, whisper.NewMessage{
        TTL:       60,
        PowTime:   2,
        PowTarget: 2.5,
        Payload:   []byte("Hello"),
        PublicKey: puKey})
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Blk:", blk)

    m, err := c.FilterMessages(ctx, fID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(m)

}
```

How I can to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the geth client. I tried that following and it worked successfully.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    shh "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/whisper/shhclient"
    whisper6 "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/whisper/whisperv6"
)

func main() {
    client, err := shh.Dial("http://127.0.0.1:8545")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    privateKeyID, err := client.NewKeyPair(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("private key id: %s\n", privateKeyID)

    filterID, err := client.NewMessageFilter(context.Background(), whisper6.Criteria{PrivateKeyID: privateKeyID})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("filter id: %s\n", filterID)

    publicKey, err := client.PublicKey(context.Background(), privateKeyID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("public key: %s\n", hexutil.Encode(publicKey))

    messageHash, err := client.Post(context.Background(), whisper6.NewMessage{
        TTL:       60,
        PowTime:   2,
        PowTarget: 2.5,
        Payload:   []byte("Hello"),
        PublicKey: publicKey,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("message hash: %s\n", messageHash)

    messages, err := client.FilterMessages(context.Background(), filterID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, message := range messages {
        fmt.Printf("message: %s", string(message.Payload))
    }
}
```

Output

```
private key id: 321025e4cc85b6d111f7a2128dd16508f9d26b50294e2bd8e89100d289987d4c
filter id: 2fd816b47ad2af291d75ce72fb19d81e33e469c29961abfd7e3c019603dd1800
public key: 0x04f5fd9240bebcd6e41d41712a51ba4775dd721963dcc92c15bddaef3da9125b298d376d884ad140da70ff456028bf2499b714042c726a64e577ee334c68956d6b
message hash: 0xb72fe6d945f2fb2a349f217d8bbccbc255014d0b0b015dedbfe3c6d4119d30f5
message: Hello
```